# Difference between tensor in mathematics and physical quantities

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, tensor-calculus, definition, linear-algebra

In mathematics, we say that a an $n$th-rank tensor in $m$-dimensional space essentially takes $n$ vectors of dimension $n$ each and converts them into a scalar. Then what do we mean when we say that physical quantities like stress are tensors?

Comment: The word stress is vague, there are   mechanical stress tensor , stress energy  tensor, electromagnetic stress tensor, for example. I guess you mean a physical example of mechanical  stress ?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscous_stress_tensor

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): The word [_scalar_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar) is in mathematical or in physical sense?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32011/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/155857/2451 and links therein.

Comment: There's no difference between the "mathematical" and "physical" meanings of tensors. For example, the stress tensor in physics takes in a vector (unit normal to a plane) and outputs a vector (force on that plane), so it's a (1, 1) tensor.

Comment: Be aware that a tensor in mathematical terms is a tensor product of one forms *and vectors*, so your definition is not quite correct.